# PostgreSQL performance of ad-hoc SQL vs functions

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, plpgsql, sql-execution-plan

Is there any difference? I know SQL queries are having their execution plans cached just as good as functions.

I foud [someone](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Monitoring-query-plan-cache-td5831561.html) telling:

> Performance is an issue, and we suspect query planning might be an 
>   underlying cause. I've rewritten the scripts from ad-hoc SQL to a 
>   Postgres functions (CREATE FUNCTION) and we saw server load go down 
>   quite a bit.

But why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query plan for ad-hoc queries is *not* cached, only for [prepared statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html). And PL/pgSQL functions handle all SQL statements like prepared statements internally. (With the notable exception of dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`.) Each for the scope of the current session, not beyond.

So PL/pgSQL functions (not SQL functions!) can help with repeated execution of sophisticated queries within the same session. Just like prepared statements.

Client software may be using prepared statements by default. Or the ["extended query" protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-overview.html#protocol-query-concepts), to the same effect.

Related:

- [No execution plan caching for dynamic SQL in PostgreSQL 9.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774115/no-execution-plan-caching-for-dynamic-sql-in-postgresql-9-4/28774924#28774924)

The related answer that started [the thread on pgsql-general](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/549564E4.4060800%40aule.net#549564E4.4060800@aule.net) you are referring to:

- [Monitoring the Postgres query parser](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86626/3684)

Also consider the chapter [Plan Caching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING) for PL/pgSQL in the manual.

Comment: I was told that Queries get their execution plan cached [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677509/postgresql-function-execution-plan-cache-principle/46678190?noredirect=1#comment80305222_46678190)

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev: That's a misunderstanding. The query plan for ad-hoc SQL statements is not cached. Only for prepared statements.

Comment: Right. I was assuming you were using prepared statements, because if you were even *thinking* about the details  of how plans are cached in functions etc, you would have already done that as the first step in reducing planning costs. Also, if the called function is an inlineable SQL function, it could be cached indirectly in calling plpgsql functions.

Comment: BTW, I think you're making a real mistake by focusing on planning time without (as far as you have shown) looking into how much planning time is actually impacting your performance. And you don't seem to be considering the *significant* overheads of doing work via the fmgr and plpgsql proc handlers etc, vs raw queries, and weighing that against planning costs. I strongly advise you not to pursue this further until you've made sure you're optimally using prepared statements across the app, at least.